# How to create web application context on demand after SpringBoot web application started

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

We have a requirement which we can change the spring context XML file on the fly  and then reload it manually, we can successfully load/reload multiple application context by the following code

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextPath);
```

by using the above code, a new application context will be created on demand, however when we try to use the same way to create a WebApplicaitonContext on demand, we failed.

My question is there any way that we can create multiple WebApplicaitonContext  on demand after SpringBoot application starts? or we can only have one webapplicationContext and my idea won't be able to be reached?

thanks

Comment: No, nor should you as that will lead to all sorts of issues. You would need to restart your application instead of creating a context.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on technical reasons to implement such a requirement? In its current form its rather impossible, but since people usually don't need to do that, probably there are other ways....

Comment: Dear M. Deinum, thanks
we don't want to restart application, we want to load several web-application-context on the fly